# opscenter shows unknown for new node

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

I have recently installed one node into the cluster and when checked in opscenter it shows the new node as unknown in the list instead of ip-address. checked in logs but doesn't say much about this. Any suggestions on how to fix this please?

Thanks

Comment: Can you include a screenshot?  Is the agent running and properly connected on this node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have ran into this issue in EC2. The VPC I was in did not have DNS hostnames enabled. Ended up putting the IP address and name of the system into /etc/hosts and then OpsCenter was able to display IP address/name with no issues.